# Correct ways to enforce implementation of inherited static methods in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

My goal is to create an abstract class whose static methods have to be implemented, but I was having some issues due to static methods not being able to be made abstract.

This is the solution I came up with:

```java
public abstract class CombinedMethod {
    public static String computeMethodBody() throws
            CannotCompileException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public static ArrayList<CtMethod>  sortSelectedMethods() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm making this post because I couldn't find any equivalent answer, which left me wondering if this is idiomatic in Java.

**Edit to add use case:**

I want to create several classes that must all implement both `computeMethodBody` and `sortSelectedMethods`.
My solution adds structure and semantic meaning to the code, compared to, for example, creating documentation explaining how to create equivalent classes.

I am aware of why overriding static methods doesn't make sense in Java and that I'm just hiding them. As I said there's no other answer exemplifying this use case, but there's plenty discussing the concept.

**Edit to add more details about the project:**

The goal here is to implement some features of Common Lisp's method combination, using annotations as modifiers.

To name an example, suppose `Class2` inherits from `Class1`:

```java
public class Class1 {
    ...
    @Combination("+")
    public int myValue()
    {
        System.out.println("In myValue of Class1");
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Class2 extends Class1 {
    ...
    @Combination("+")
    public int myValue()
    {
        System.out.println("In myValue of Class2");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Since they're both annotated with "+", I want to change the behaviour of this method at load time, so that Class2's effective method will be something behaviourally equivalent to:

```
    @Combination("+")
    public int myValue()
    {
        System.out.println("In myValue of Class2");
        System.out.println("In myValue of Class1");
        return 2 + 1;
    }
```

To do so, I employed Javassist to compute a new effective method. Fortunately, I was able to generalize my architecture, so adding new functionality entails creating a static method and calling it inside a new `switch case` statement:

```java
    String computeEffectiveMethodBody(String annotationValue, CtClass ctClass, ArrayList<CtMethod> sortedSelectedMethods) throws CannotCompileException {
        switch (annotationValue) {
            case "min":
                return CombinedMin.computeMethodBody(ctClass, sortedSelectedMethods);
            case "max":
                return CombinedMax.computeMethodBody(ctClass, sortedSelectedMethods);
            case "+":
                return CombinedAddition.computeMethodBody(ctClass, sortedSelectedMethods);
            case "and":
                return CombinedAnd.computeMethodBody(ctClass, sortedSelectedMethods);
            case "or":
                return CombinedOr.computeMethodBody(ctClass, sortedSelectedMethods);
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid annotation");
        }
    }
```

The way I choose to segregate it was by creating a package called `combinedMethods`. Inside it, there's the parent function `CombinedMethod` and another subpackage called `methods` where all of the extensions with the actual static methods are kept.

Thank you @AasmundEldhuset for your interest, I'm always looking for the best way to architecture my software, even though I haven't learned it formally yet.

Comment: You can't call them polymorphically, so what is the use case for this pattern?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is a good reason that static methods can't be abstract, which is what @khelwood describes. While they can be _shadowed_ in a subclass, that's not the same thing as overriding; the subclass method is completely unrelated to the superclass method. The concept of abstract methods doesn't apply to static methods since they are not invoked via dynamic dispatch. There is likely a better way to solve the higher-level issue you are facing, so please describe that.

Comment: `static` methods are not overriden. Maybe you should state with an example what you want to achieve, with a clear goal.

Comment: And, the answer is that you can't do it in the Java language.  You might be able to do it with custom FindBugs (or similar) rules but that's probably not what you mean by "force".

Comment: @khelwood I updated the answer with my use case. Would you say that not being able to "call them polymorphically" invalidates the use of inheritance/abstraction here?

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I'm aware why this limitiation is in place, I wasn't trying to create abstract static methods, just trying to enforce their shadowing.

Comment: It isn't a "use of inheritance": it's some static methods in one class and separate static methods in another class. I still don't see what benefit that confers, but do it if you want.

Comment: @DMeneses: In that case, the only alternatives to your solution that I'm aware of are to either: A. Just don't declare the methods in the superclass at all (they don't provide any value to the subclasses besides misleadingly showing up in autocompletion); or B. Write a static analyzer (or a reflection-based unit test) that finds all subclasses of your class and checks whether they have their own methods with those names. I'm still curious about why you need this, though. Could you demonstrate the code that would be calling these functions?

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset yes I understand your points, implementing a static analyzer or documentation would be overkill as this is just a uni project. my teacher doesn't agree much with this but I find the solutions he proposed more cumbersome to program. My ultimate goal with inheritance here is just forcing a certain structure on the code. And in my view, inheriting from that useless parent class adds semantic meaning to how the different subclasses are related. I'll update the post now

Answer (score 1):

> enforce implementation of inherited static methods in Java?

[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) says:

> A class does **not inherit** private or **static methods** from its superinterface types.

Static methods are also called **class methods**. They are bound to a class and don't require an instance of the class in order to be invoked.

`static` and `abstract` is an illegal combination of modifiers because static methods are completely self-contained and always have an implementation.

You can not inherit `static` methods and as subsequence the concept of **overriding** is not applicable to them. And since a *subclass* can not override a *parent's* `static` method, `abstract static` method doesn't make sense because it *can not be implemented*.

A class method can be ***hidden*** by a method from a *subclass* with the same *signature*.

A quote from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2):

> A class (static) method that is hidden can be **invoked by using a reference** whose type is the type of the class that actually **contains the declaration** of the method. In this respect, hiding of static methods is different from overriding of instance methods.

I.e. ***hidden*** version can be invoked only on a *child* class or instance, conversely to the ***overridden*** method which can be invoked on the instance on of *parent* class or on the instance on of *child* class.

In other words, you can't obtain polymorphic behavior with `static` methods.

---

**UPDATE**

> I want to create several classes that must all implement both `computeMethodBody` and `sortSelectedMethods`

So you want these two `static` methods with the same signature to be present in a couple of classes. And that's totally fine. But you don't need a *parent* `abstract` class for that because there's no useful code in it if both its method will be hidden.

> creating documentation explaining how to create equivalent classes

Inheritance in **Object-Oriented Programming** isn't used for documentary purposes. The *child* should be capable to replace its *parent* in any use-cases, as Liskov substitution principle suggests.

The problem is that there are no use-cases for such a *parent* class. `combinedMethod` class isn't designed for inheritance (*BTW, it's not a very informative name and by convention names of classes and interfaces should start with a capital letter*).

You are misusing inheritance. If you need to provide the end-users of your classes with some additional information, there are other ways to do that:

- The very first mean is a [**self-documenting code**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). Use clear, concise and self-explanatory names for your methods and classes.
- Since **Java 5** metadata can be provided with *annotations*.
- In earlier versions, *marker-interfaces* were used for that purpose. But classes **were never utilized** for that.

Another thing that you need to understand is that although inheritance is a very important and useful mechanism, it also has pitfalls and should be applied after careful consideration.

Even if your case would be more suitable to apply inheritance, it wouldn't automatically mean that inheritance is the best option.

For instance, classes `IntSummaryStatistics`, `LongSummaryStatistics` and `DoubleSummaryStatistics` have **no** parent class in the **JDK**, although they have common fields and behavior.

Take a look at these classes a compare with your situation when *parent* isn't designed to be extended and has nothing to offer to its *subclasses*.

If you need to provide metadata - you can create a custom annotation like `@CapableOfSomething` and mark your classes with it, but don't abuse inheritance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are invoked on a class, independent of an instance, so if they would be abstract, how would the run-time know on which sub-class to call them?

```
CombinedMethod cm1 = new SubclassA(...)
CombinedMethod cm2 = new SubclassB(...)

// static method computeMethodBody is called on neither cm1 or cm2, so what implementation to choose.
String result = CombinedMethod.computeMethodBody();
```